# Encontrar determinada palavra em um determinado usuário Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter-api

Seguindo a documentação, consegui criar um código que extrai tweets por TAg, e outro que extrai tweets de algum usuário. Mas estou com problemas na hora de extrair tweets de alguem por tag.

```
resultado = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at,tweet.coordinates,tweet.geo,tweet.truncated,tweet.text] for tweet in alltweets if tweet.text == 'palavra_chave']
```

O código só baixa tweets que contém unicamente a palavra-chave.
Por exemplo, a palavra-chave é 'Hoje'. Se o tweet for 'Hoje o dia foi bom', ele não identifica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é porque você requer, na sua compreensão de lista, que o texto seja exatamente igual à palavra chave:

```
... for tweet in alltweets if tweet.text == 'palavra_chave']
```

Se quer verificar que a palavra chave está dentro do tweet, deve usar o operador `in`:

```
... for tweet in alltweets if 'palavra_chave' in tweet.text]
```